# Split a list in prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog

suppose i have this list in prolog:

```
[-0.791666666666667-[]-[predicate(a,b,c,d)]-[predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)]]
```

there is way to split this in:

```
-0.791666666666667, [], [predicate(a,b,c,d)], [predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)] ???
```

Split means have different pice of the list.

Maybe:

```
X = -0.791666666666667  Y = []  Z = [predicate(a,b,c,d)] etc...
```

Or another solution can be replace - with "," so it become a list with different elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching. Similar to the way you use it on lists (`[H|T]`):

```
split(A, R) :- split(A, R, []).

split(A-B, R, Acc) :- split(A, R, [B|Acc]), !.
split(H, [H|T], T).
```

I'm using accumulator, because something like `a-b-c` is split by `A-B` into `a-b` and `c`.

**EDIT:** If you know you have 4 terms, you can use something like

```
split(A-B-C-D, A, B, C, D).
```

Comment: ok thank you. but if i know the number of element to split how i can simplify this ?  i know that for each list i have just 4 terms.

Comment: wait if i write split([-0.791666666666667-[]-[predicate(a,b,c,d)]-[predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)]],X).
it write X = [[-0.791666666666667-[]-[predicate(a,b,c,d)]-[predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)]]] why ?

Comment: `split(-0.791666666666667-[]-[predicate(a,b,c,d)]-[predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)],A,B,C,D).` should work.

Comment: you have tested you predicate in prolog ?

Answer (score 0):

Trivial:

```
to_list([A-B-C-D], [A,B,C,D]).
```

Usage:

```
?- to_list([-0.791666666666667-[]-[predicate(a,b,c,d)]-[predicate_2(p,e,q,d,g)]],
           L).
L = [-0.791667, [], [predicate(a, b, c, d)], [predicate_2(p, e, q, d, g)]].
```

Or do the pattern matching inline, it's rather wasteful to write a predicate for such a task, which seems rather one-off to me.